Cucumber / behave idiom for doing a lengthy task once?
I'm using Cucumber / behave to test BLE connectivity with a device.  One step -- establishing the connection -- is a lengthy task, taking several seconds.  Once I have the connection, I'd like to run a bunch of other tests (checking security, establishing a session, etc).
I know that best practices would (A) start each scenario with a clean state and (B) not hide hidden state from the user (e.g. with before_scenario and whatnot).  But in this case, it seems appropriate to start a scenario with something like Given a connected BLE device so I don't need to reconnect for each test.
What would be best practices to implement something like this?

In practice there's always a certain amount of state when performing cucumber tests.  For example, a web site test usually presumes that the servers are powered up, connected to the network, etc.  Since connecting with the device is a step that you'd like to perform once at the start of the suite, you can probably make use of either the startup or a pre-suite hook to perform the connection.  a Given a connected BLE device step in a Background section would make it evident without having to repeat for each scenario. Be sure the state is clean enough between scenarios that they don't interfere with each other.  Using hooks to perform any necessary cleanup avoids cluttering up the Gherkin test descriptions.

Helpful - thanks!  I'm sure it's in the docs, but what variable holds state across Scenarios but gets reset for each new Feature?  I expect I could use that to implement Given a connected BLE device.

The two key points:

context.feature persists across all Scenarios within a Feature
context.random_attribute gets reset for each Feature

With that in mind, here's one way to implement things.  Assume that set_stage() is an expensive, time-consuming operation and raise_curtain() is fast.  We save the stage state in context.feature and the curtain state in context:
# file: test.feature
Feature: Testing Feature and Scenario persistent state

  Scenario: Set stage
    Given the stage is set
    Then the curtain is down

  Scenario: Raise curtain
    Given the stage is set
    When the curtain rises
    Then the curtain is up

  Scenario: Start show
    Given the stage is set
    When the curtain rises
    Then the curtain is up
    And the actors are visible

"""
File: test_steps.py
Examine the behavior of context across Features and Scenarios
"""
from behave import *

def stage_is_set(context):
    return hasattr(context.feature, 'stage_is_set') and context.feature.stage_is_set == True

def set_stage(context):
    if not stage_is_set(context):
        print(f'=== setting the stage', flush=True)
        context.feature.stage_is_set = True

def curtain_is_up(context):
    return hasattr(context, 'curtain_is_up') and context.curtain_is_up == True

def raise_curtain(context):
    if not curtain_is_up(context):
        print(f'=== raising the curtain', flush=True)
        context.curtain_is_up = True

@given(u'the stage is set')
def step_impl(context):
    set_stage(context)

@when(u'the curtain rises')
def step_impl(context):
    raise_curtain(context)

@then(u'the curtain is down')
def step_impl(context):
    assert not curtain_is_up(context)

@then(u'the curtain is up')
def step_impl(context):
    assert curtain_is_up(context)

@then(u'the actors are visible')
def step_impl(context):
    assert stage_is_set(context) and curtain_is_up(context)

When the test is run:
Feature: Testing Feature and Scenario persistent state # features/test.feature:1

  Scenario: Set stage        # features/test.feature:3
    Given the stage is set   # features/steps/test_steps.py:22
=== setting the stage
    Then the curtain is down # features/steps/test_steps.py:30

  Scenario: Raise curtain  # features/test.feature:7
    Given the stage is set # features/steps/test_steps.py:22
    When the curtain rises # features/steps/test_steps.py:26
=== raising the curtain
    Then the curtain is up # features/steps/test_steps.py:34

  Scenario: Start show         # features/test.feature:12
    Given the stage is set     # features/steps/test_steps.py:22
    When the curtain rises     # features/steps/test_steps.py:26
=== raising the curtain
    Then the curtain is up     # features/steps/test_steps.py:34
    And the actors are visible # features/steps/test_steps.py:38

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
3 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
9 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.001s

Note that === setting the stage only happens once within the Feature despite multiple calls to Given the stage is set, whereas === raising the curtain happens at each call to When the curtain rises.
